# Группировка датафрейма по части строки и подсчет номеров элементов внутри группы

Tags: python, pandas

По первым двум цифрам числа нужно сгруппировать колонку и посчитать номера элементов внутри группы

Датафрейм:

```
01256
01369
01458
01358
24785
24789
24365
24157
27894
27444
```

Нужно получить ->

```
01256 1
01369 2
01458 3
01358 4
24785 1
24789 2
24365 3
24157 4
27894 1 
27444 2
```

как сделать?

Comment: Принцип то объясните? По первым двум цифрам числа нужно сгруппировать и посчитать внутри группы или что? Или просто по четвёркам именно посчитать? Непонятно.

Comment: да, по первым двум цифрам числа нужно сгруппировать и посчитать внутри группы

Answer (score 2):

Ну буквально так и делаете:

- выделяете первые две цифры
- делаете по ним группировку
- используете `cumcount` для подсчёта номера внутри группы

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
"""01256
01369
01458
01358
24785
24789
24365
24157
27894
27444""".split('\n'), 
columns=['num']
)
df['ord'] = df.groupby(df['num'].str.slice(0,2)).cumcount() + 1
df
```

На выходе:

```
     num   ord
0   01256   1
1   01369   2
2   01458   3
3   01358   4
4   24785   1
5   24789   2
6   24365   3
7   24157   4
8   27894   1
9   27444   2
```

Comment: Спасибо) Не думал, что так просто)